# How to generate binary .deb file of a ROS package locally without ROS buldfarm

Tags: ros, binary, deb, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

During our  work, we need some binary .deb package of some ROS packages.  I only need a local manner to generate a ".deb" file to obfuscate my source code and thereby, the other can use the package without seeing the source code.

I have been digging around the ROS release process and ros buldfarm. But things are not really clear to us yet. Would you please  suggestion me how to do, or how would you advise us to do in order to generate such installers package?

Your suggestion and help to solve this is pretty appreciated.

Best,

Rickardo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235877/how-to-generate-binary-.deb-file-of-a-ros-package-locally-without-ros-buldfarm/) by [Rickardo Leos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3712/rickardo-leos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been asked before. See if [Build Debian Package Locally?](http://answers.ros.org/question/67345) answers your question.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rickardo Leos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3712/rickardo-leos/) on 2016-06-02**:
Thanks, what I mean is to build my own package locally without a repository

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-02**:
Without using Bloom, I think the level of automation is going to be limited. You could perhaps use a local release repository (a git repo on your local machine, with a `file://..` url). Then GPB. Or maybe `checkinstall` is an option. Or even just copy the files from the install location.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-02**:
Depending on what your package does/needs, you could see whether building with regular CMake works (`mkdir build; cd build; cmake ..` etc). If it does, `checkinstall` should be able to create a debian for you. Or maybe `fpm`, or CMake's own package generation infrastructure.

**Comment by [Rickardo Leos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3712/rickardo-leos/) on 2016-06-02**:
Many thanks, [gvdhoorn](http://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) . I have tried cheinstall, but failed. Could you please show me the detail for this process. Cheers. What I need is to create a binary deb of my own package and share it to the others without the source code for some reason.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-02**:
"but failed" is a bit vague. If you could update your question with what you tried, and any error messages that produced we might be able to help you.

**Comment by [GL](https://answers.ros.org/users/134453/gl/) on 2023-01-17**:
Same question here! I had problems using checkinstall. I was installing my packages in a custom directory and trying to pack it. But after the checkinstall command and compilation the deb file is empty. Do you know what could be happen?